# React application showing "404 page not found " error when open in new tab

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Have migrated a react application from my local environment to live server, post migration the menu links are throwing a 404 error if opened in new tab.

website link : http://www.plejfitness.com/
Menu location : Top right header menu

```
<ul class="_1xWsKFr _2rbE6TC _2v5bHvx pRZSkbx">
    <li class="_1GxILA2">
        <a aria-current="page" class="_2Vj-OOq _2_HaYMw _1w_OEYg active" href="/">
            Home
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="_1GxILA2">
        <a class="_2Vj-OOq _2_HaYMw _1w_OEYg" href="/about">
            About Us
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="_1GxILA2">
        <a class="_2Vj-OOq _2_HaYMw _1w_OEYg" href="/contact-us">
            Join PLEJ Fitness
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="_1GxILA2">
        <a class="_2Vj-OOq _2_HaYMw _1w_OEYg" href="/location">
            Locations
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="_1GxILA2">
        <a class="_2Vj-OOq _2_HaYMw _1w_OEYg" href="/careers">
            Careers
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="_1GxILA2">
        <a class="_2Vj-OOq _2_HaYMw _1w_OEYg" href="/owngym">
            Own A Gym
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="_1GxILA2">
        <a class="_2Vj-OOq _2_HaYMw _1w_OEYg" href="/gallery">
            Gallery
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="_1GxILA2">
        <a class="_2Vj-OOq _2_HaYMw _1w_OEYg" href="/contact-us">
            Contact Us
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Where is your React code? Looks like React-Router is not configured correctly. Your site seems to be a single page app, so it looks like the routing is not working correctly in a new tab.

Comment: did it work locally?

Comment: Yes it works fine on local version

Comment: That's your server's 404 page you're seeing, not your React app. Your server is not configured to serve your app on those paths, only on `/`

Answer (score 1):

An .htaccess file with following code in the root folder has fixed the issue

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this creating a _redirects file in the public directory.

Inside it paste this:

/*  /index.html  200

This allows to open link (and also copy-paste URL) in a new tab.